# "whom...must...": is this real sentence grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, grammatical-case, whom

I encountered [this curious sentence](https://books.google.com/books?id=oOxEAQAAMAAJ&ppis=_e&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q=whom&f=false) on page 234 of the 1859
novel *Natalie; or, A Gem Among the Sea-Weeds*, by Emma V. Hallet
writing under the pseudonym “Ferna Vale”, marked here in bold:

> In a few words he informed her of what he had learned from Mrs.
> Santon the day previous, but what was his astonishment to find
> her totally ignorant of the circumstances, not hesitating to
> declare the whole a base falsehood.

> “I had not a doubt of the falsity of the report,” said
> Delwood; “but what can have given rise to such a statement?
> Surely, your mother would not wish to injure my feelings, by
> repeating what may have originated, without foundation, among
> the servants, and she could not have herself credited!”

> **Winnie saw the truth at once, knowing as she did the
> character of her, whom, if she had ever looked upon as a
> mother, must from this moment forfeit every claim upon her
> feelings, unless it were that of utter contempt.**

> “Mr. Delwood,” said she, raising herself to her full
> height, her slender fingers clenched together, every nerve
> ’roused to action, — “if you would not insult me, never
> again call the woman who has had the heart to cast such a slur
> upon the character of her whom we know is innocent, *my
> mother!* It is not to injure your feelings that she has
> invented such a vile scheme, but it is by injuring Natalie’s
> character in your eyes, she may banish from her heart all
> future happiness. Nay, do not start at such a strange
> declaration from my lips; you are the only person, out of my
> father’s household, who has a suspicion that our happiness is
> not what it once was; but since it has come to this, I will, at
> the risk of disclosing to the world what it were wisdom to
> conceal, establish the innocent; and rest assure that what I
> say is true, — this has originated not amonth the servants,
> for there is not but would kneel and kiss the very ground upon
> which are dear Sea-flower treads.”

(The context is that Winnie’s new stepmother has proven to be an
ill-natured woman.)

The *whom* seems to be correct (accusative case, I think: she had ever
looked upon HER), but then the “must from this moment...” feels
disjointed, not properly connected to the first part of the sentence.

Is this use of *whom* in fact correct? How would one analyse the
complete sentence in question?

Comment: I think ***whom*** here is a pronoun referencing preceding noun ***her*** - but it's the ***subject*** of following verb ***must***, so it should be the "nominative" form ***who***. This should be easier to see if you remove the optional "parenthetical" element ***if she had ever looked upon as a mother***. But the overall syntax is almost certainly syntactically flawed as well as being hopelessly convoluted. I'm not sure, but it seems to me that highlighted parenthetical element needs to include a pronoun referencing "her" (the "mother") as well as "she" (Winnie).

Comment: ...or maybe *if she had ever **been** looked upon as a mother.* It's a syntactic mess.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't see any way out of this matrix maze using *whom*. The penultimate clause still requires a subject, and the subject can't be *whom*, so what can it be?

Comment: The sentence is like an intelligence test! As I read it, the words [in brackets] should be omitted, and the words (in parentheses) are explanatory: “Winnie saw the truth at once, knowing [*as she did*] **that** the character (i.e. that person) [*of her, whom, if she (i.e. Winnie) had ever (=at any time) looked upon as a mother*,] must from this moment forfeit every claim upon her feelings, unless it were that of utter contempt.”

Comment: @Greybeard: I can't put my finger on exactly why, but I found it hard to figure out exactly how the parenthetical element related to the surrounding statement until I though of sticking the whole thing in brackets and replacing ***if*** with ***regardless of whether***. At which point it just seemed obvious to me that preceding ***her, whom*** should be replaced by ***she who***. It's certainly "taxing"!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In

> Winnie saw the truth at once, knowing as she did the character of her,
>   whom, if she had ever looked upon as a mother, must from this moment
>   forfeit every claim upon her feelings, unless it were that of utter
>   contempt.

the parenthetical and other additions to the matrix sentence complicate analysis.

Stripping to an easier but comparable (grammatically at the salient point) stripped example:

> Winnie met the woman who must acknowledge that she had no right to
>   expect any sympathy from Winnie.

The parenthetical in the original does not control the grammar of the matrix sentence, so nominative 'who' is the correct pronoun.

(As FF points out in a comment, the parenthetical should be [and this even if Winnie had ever regarded her as a mother]. Parentheticals need to fit with the matrix sentence better than is the case in the original.) Also, 'unless it were' would nowadays sound better rendered 'except perhaps for a feeling of utter contempt'.

Comment: The ***who / whom*** business seems reasonably straightforward. But I don't like the structure of the parenthetical element. Maybe *if she had ever **been** looked upon as a mother* OR *if she had ever looked upon **her** as a mother* would fix things, but however I try to parse it, things seem to unravel both syntactically and semantically.

Comment: Yes; I've changed the parenthetical. It doesn't match the grammar of the matrix sentence exactly, but doesn't grind against it either.

Comment: Modeled after *I know the character of **she who must be obeyed***, which seems fine to me, I also can't help thinking existing **her, whom** should be **she who** (without a comma). But the whole thing is starting to boil my brain now! :)

Comment: If you look through the specimina selected by the Google Books link I put in the question, you will come across other instances where the author has again used *whom* “curiously” meaning as the subject of a finite clause. ⁋ 50: “..to that Great Spirit, **whom** he had been taught **was** the one great Father of all.”
⁋ 67: “..but he, declining all assistance from those, **whom** he knew **gave** not grudgingly, thanks them with a grateful heart..”
⁋ 249: “..for the sake of the child, **whom** she knew **was** not her own by kindred..”